# ¿Cómo obtener el signo de moneda guaraní en Oracle?

Tags: oracle

[image: simbolo moneda guarani]

Quiero ese símbolo para usar así:

`₲10.000`

y me aparece así:

`?10.000`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Querés que aparezca ese símbolo en lugar de `PYG`? No olvides leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Quiero ese simbolo para usar asi ₲10.000 y me aparece asi  ?10.000

Comment: Eso es relevante para tu pregunta: pulsá en [edit] y agregá lo que escribiste en tu comentario. Además, mostrá lo que intentaste hasta el momento.

Comment: Hola! Eso es oracle forms? En qué aplicación y que versión se pintan los datos? Lo otro: podrías por favor poner como texto la consulta que estás usando? Es para poder replicar tu problema (procura compartir este tipo de cosas como texto, así como no te vamos a poner a transcribir imagenes). Por favor sigue los otros comentarios y usa la opción para editar tu pregunta :)

Comment: Además, no olvides que el código y los mensajes de error (si los hay) deben ir _como texto, con formato_. ¡No se puede hacer _copy-paste_ para probar la consulta si es una imagen! Aparte de eso: ¿cuál es tu `NLS_LANG`?

Comment: en pl/sql funciona asi SELECT unistr('\20B2') FROM DUAL; y mi NLS_LANG esAMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8